# using .net classes obtained form web services in flex

Tags: .net, apache-flex, actionscript-3, web-services

from flex, when calling a .net web method that returns a custom class, I always recieve an ObjectProxy, even if I have the same class created on flex. How do I manage this ObjectProxy as the class I have?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use custom classes with WebServices they need to be registered with `SchemaTypeRegistry`.  You'll need to map the namespace and local name from the wsdl to an AS3 class.